# WebClient.UploadFile issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webclient

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ASP.Net. I am using WebClient.UploadFile to upload file to a server running with ASP.Net (I use http post to upload the file to a aspx url). My question is, how to save the content of the file at server side? I find from server side, if I simply save HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream, additional request headers (besides file content) will be saved at server side.

EDIT 1:

I have tried I need to have some code like this to receive file at server side? Is that correct code?

```
    foreach (string f in Request.Files.AllKeys)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[f];
        file.SaveAs(@"D:\FileUpload\UploadFile.dat");
    }
```

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2):

You can read the stream into a byte array and then save the byte array in a varbinary(max) field in SQL server.

Comment: Sorry maybe I have not made myself understood. I mean at server side, how to receive the file content (which is using WebClient.UploadFile to upload)?

Comment: I have found a solution by myself. I have posted my solution in EDIT 1 section of my post. Could you review whether my code is correct please? Thanks!

Comment: From your code it looks like the second file will overwrite the first

Comment: Yes, it is just for proof of concept purpose. For other parts like how to receive file, is my code correct? Thanks.